# Bulk update a column in Oracle 11G

Tags: merge, oracle11g, bulk

I have two tables say Table1 and Table2 that contains the following column with which I should join and perform an update a column of Table1 with the value of the same column present in Table2.

Columns for Join condition:

1. Table1.mem_ssn and Table2.ins_ssn
2. Table1.sys_id and Table2.sys_id
3. Table1.grp_id and Table2.grp_id

Column to update:

Table1.dtofhire=Table2.dtofhire

I need a way to bulk update (using single update query without looping)  the above mentioned column in Oracle 11G.

Table1 does not contain any key constraint specified since it will be used as a staging table for Data upload.

Please help me out to update the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that I used to arrive the functionality is seen below

```
UPDATE table1  T2 
SET    dtofhire = (SELECT Max(dtofhire) AS dtofhire 
           FROM   table2 T1 
           WHERE  T2.mem_ssn = T1.ins_ssn 
              AND T2.sys_id = T1.sys_id 
              AND T2.grp_id = T1.grp_id 
           GROUP  BY ins_ssn, 
               sys_id, 
               grp_id) 
WHERE  ( mem_ssn, sys_id, grp_id ) IN (SELECT ins_ssn, 
                        sys_id, 
                        grp_id 
                     FROM   table2 );
```

Comment: This will be a little bit slower one and error prone dur to "IN". High equality checks and limits in "IN" set. Better approach would be @A.B.Cade 's

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm) statement.
It should look something like this:

```
MERGE INTO table1 D
   USING (SELECT * FROM table2 ) S
   ON (D.mem_ssn = S.ins_ssn and D.sys_id = S.sys_id and D.grp_id=S.grp_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE SET D.dtofhire=S.dtofhire;
```

**UPDATE:**
Since you have more than one row in table2 with the same (ins_ssn,sys_id,grp_id) and you want the max `dtofhire`, you should change the query in the using clause:

```
 MERGE INTO table1 D
   USING (SELECT ins_ssn, sys_id, grp_id, max(dtofhire) m_dtofhire
            FROM table2 
        GROUP BY ins_ssn,sys_id,grp_id) S
   ON (D.mem_ssn = S.ins_ssn and D.sys_id = S.sys_id and D.grp_id=S.grp_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
     UPDATE SET D.dtofhire=S.m_dtofhire;
```

Comment: Thanks Cade but getting the following error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: Do you have more than one row in table2 with the same (ins_ssn,sys_id,grp_id) ?

Comment: Yes Cade I get more than one row retreived from Table 2 for the query. For this I'm going to update the highest date say 05/02/2012 in 05/02/2012 and 05/03/1999

Comment: Thanks Cade for replying.. I did find a way to update the same